# xclip hangs shell-command

Tags: linux, shell-command

I like to use the `xclip` utility to capture the output of commands on the clipboard. However, when I try to use it with `shell-command` it seems to hang.

In a "normal" shell I can run a command such as `echo "hello world" | xclip -selection clipboard` and it will return almost immediately and copy `hello world` to the clipboard. When I try to run the same command from `shell-command` the command seems to "hang": the focus stays in the minibuffer and I can't do anything until I cancel the command with `C-g`. After cancelling the command the text has been copied to the clipboard though.

I'm running emacs 24.4.1 on Debian 8.6

Any idea why the xclip command hangs?

Comment: use `xsel` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xclip` has to "hang" around to own the clipboard, as X uses asynchronous clipboards which belong to a process. You should be able to get away with just using `async-shell-command`, which is bound to <kbd>M-&</kbd> by default. Another solution would be to use some clipboard manager instead.

Comment: Doing some research on `xsel` led me to some other information that helped clarify things for me. The way `xclip` is implemented is that it forks a child to manage the copied data and `stdout` is kept open. It seems that `stdout` being kept open is the immediate cause for `shell-command` not returning. Redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null` (e.g. `hello world" | xclip -selection clipboard &> /dev/null`) causes `shell-command` to return immediately as expected.

Comment: This above comment is actually exactly what I needed to find out. Not emacs-specific and a very useful piece of information. Thanks!

Comment: And, if you `xclip` call is within a shell script that you call from Emacs, the `&> /dev/null` must be appended to the shell script call instead of the `xclip`.

Comment: This first comment should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Right, Commands such as `(shell-command "xclip -selection clipboard -o")` hang unless the clipboard has the "right" content either text or image.

As a workaround, you can terminate it by using `timeout TIMEOUT`.

## An example:

When only plain text exists in the clipboard and you use

```
(shell-command (format "xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > %s" image-file))
```

to get the plain text saved as an `image-file`, emacs will hang until you `Ctrl-g` to terminate it by force.

Adding `Timeout 0.05` as

```
(shell-command (format "timeout 0.05 xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > %s" image-file))
```

will end the `xclip` process after `0.05`.